# Migrate from DPM to Azure Backup Server (MABS)

Tags: backup, azure, scdpm

We have been using Microsoft System Center Data Protection Manager (DPM) for a number of years, with a few years of backup data. We would like to migrate to Microsoft Azure Backup Server (MABS) and have used this free version of DPM at a number of our sites over the last 12 months.

We would like to keep our existing backups at the sites running DPM and migrate these to MABS.  Are there any methods of moving our on-site and Azure cloud-based DPM backups to MABS?

We have tried using the methods Microsoft recommended for migrating DPM to DPM, eg. a new server, or software version upgrade, however, the database is not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

The major issue in migration is the incompatibility of databases in both tools as they have separate encryption methods.
I would recommend retaining the current backed up data till its retention expires and move the future data on MABS.
As an alternate, you can try any cloud-based backup tool with Azure integration like Cloudberry to backup up the data while migration, so that you can eliminate the copies with longer retention and move the cloudberry server for a shorter retention till all the servers are migrated to your new server.